# Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, key, vuesax

Hi I have meet the error as following, even I add the :key bind still show the error.
I have tried to add the key in the template but it show the error template cannot be keyed

```
ERROR MESSAGE : Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive
```

[image]

Comment: You need to have a primitive value as :key. date looks like it's an object, so trying replacing this with `:key="provider.code + '-' + date.date"`

Comment: oh thanks 
I have solve with it
`:key="provider.code + '-' + date.date + '-' + i"`